# Establishing quine type in scala

Tags: scala, types, recursive-datastructures, quine

I have to parse a string with syntax

```
lazy val expr: Parser[Term ~ Option[<recursion>]] = term ~ opt(expr)
```

You see, it uses itself to parse subexpressions. But what does this type result in? In order to reproduce the problem, I [created](http://scastie.org/20565) a somewhat similar problem

```
def quine(depth: Int, result: (Any, Option[Any])): (Any, Option[Any]) = 
    if (depth == 0) result else {quine(depth - 1, (depth, Some(result)))}
quine(5, (true, None))
```

As you see, I used `Any` since I do not know how to give exact type.

The lists somehow define proto type `List[A]`, extended by `Cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A])` and some magic `Nil`. This allows the list to recur somehow. But, what should I do in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here, because your `result` type is different between the function definition and invocation (the first element is `Int` in the former and `Boolean` in the latter, that can't work).

But, provided that was just a typo, something like this should do the trick:

```
 case class Quine(n: Int, q: Option[Quine])
 def quine(depth: Int, result: Quine): Quine =  
  if (depth == 0) result else 
    quine(depth - 1, Quine(depth, Some(result)))

 quine(5, Quine(6, None))
```